# Sentence in a white rectangle

Tags: formatting, luatex

I would like to add to my document sentences which summarize the parts of the text, like this:

[image: What I would like to get]

Let's say that I try to reproduce [this HTML page](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_R%C3%A9publique_(trad._Chambry)/Livre_VII).

The best I found is this:

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
\textbf{\textit{L’allégorie de}}\\
\textbf{\textit{la caverne.}}
\end{tabular}
Maintenant, repris-je,
```

But as you can see in the following image, it doesn't produce exactly the desired result.

[image: Result]

Here a MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,french]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=20mm}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}
[
  Extension      = .otf ,
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  Numbers        = Lowercase,
  Ligatures      = Discretionary,
  Style          = Swash
]
% https://texnique.fr/osqa/questions/8423/lualatex-et-ligatures

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage \hspace{1pt} / \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}[0]{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\Large
Allégorie de la caverne.
\end{center}

\thispagestyle{fancy}

%~ L’allégorie de
%~ la caverne.

%~ I

\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
\textbf{\textit{L’allégorie de}}\\
\textbf{\textit{la caverne.}}
\end{tabular}
Maintenant, repris-je, représente-toi notre nature, selon qu’elle est ou qu’elle n’est pas éclairée par l’éducation, d’après le tableau que voici. Figure-toi des hommes dans une demeure souterraine en forme de caverne, dont l’entrée, ouverte à la lumière, s’étend sur toute la longueur de la façade ; ils sont là depuis leur enfance, les jambes et le cou pris dans des chaînes, en sorte qu’ils ne peuvent bouger de place, ni voir ailleurs que devant eux ; car les liens les empêchent de tourner la tête ; la lumière d’un feu allumé au loin sur une hauteur brille derrière eux ; entre le feu et les prisonniers il y a une route élevée ; le long de cette route figure-toi un petit mur, pareil aux cloisons que les montreurs de marionnettes dressent entre eux et le public et au-dessus desquelles ils font voir leurs prestiges.

Je vois cela, dit-il.

Figure-toi maintenant le long de ce petit mur des hommes portant des ustensiles de toute sorte, qui dépassent la hauteur du mur, et des figures d’hommes et d’animaux, en pierre, en bois, de toutes sortes de formes ; et naturellement parmi ces porteurs qui défilent, les uns parlent, les autres ne disent rien.

Voilà, dit-il, un étrange tableau et d’étranges prisonniers.

Ils nous ressemblent, répondis-je. Et d’abord penses-tu que dans cette situation ils aient vu d’eux-mêmes et de leurs voisins autre chose que les ombres projetées par le feu sur la partie de la caverne qui leur fait face ?

Peut-il en être autrement, dit-il, s’ils sont contraints toute leur vie de rester la tête immobile ?

Et des objets qui défilent, n’en est-il pas de même ?

Sans contredit.

Dès lors, s’ils pouvaient s’entretenir entre eux, ne penses-tu pas qu’ils croiraient nommer les objets réels eux-mêmes, en nommant les ombres qu’ils verraient ?

Nécessairement.

\begin{flushright}
\large\textsc{platon}, \textit{La République}, livre VII.

\bigskip\footnotesize Traduction Chambry.
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see the lettrine or wrapfig packages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As David already told in a comment, you can use, e.g., [package `wrapfig`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) (I've shorten the example to relevant parts of code and text):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,french]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newcommand{\startparwith}[2][3]{%
  \begin{wrapfigure}[#1]{l}{0pt}
    \parbox{.333\textwidth}{\centering\bfseries\itshape#2}%
  \end{wrapfigure}%
  \noindent\ignorespaces
}  

\begin{document}

\section*{\centering Allégorie de la caverne.}

\startparwith[4]{%
  L’allégorie de\\
  la caverne
}%
Maintenant, repris-je, représente-toi notre nature, selon qu’elle est ou qu’elle n’est pas éclairée par l’éducation, d’après le tableau que voici. Figure-toi des hommes dans une demeure souterraine en forme de caverne, dont l’entrée, ouverte à la lumière, s’étend sur toute la longueur de la façade ; ils sont là depuis leur enfance, les jambes et le cou pris dans des chaînes, en sorte qu’ils ne peuvent bouger de place, ni voir ailleurs que devant eux ; car les liens les empêchent de tourner la tête ; la lumière d’un feu allumé au loin sur une hauteur brille derrière eux ; entre le feu et les prisonniers il y a une route élevée ; le long de cette route figure-toi un petit mur, pareil aux cloisons que les montreurs de marionnettes dressent entre eux et le public et au-dessus desquelles ils font voir leurs prestiges.

\end{document}
```

[image: using wrapfig]

Alternatively, you can use [package `wrapfig2`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig2), that provides an additional environment `wraptext`, which makes the usage IMHO very simple:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,french]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{wrapfig2}

\newcommand{\startparwith}[1]{%
  \begin{wraptext}{l}
    \centering\bfseries\itshape#1\par
  \end{wraptext}%
  \noindent\ignorespaces
}  

\begin{document}

\section*{\centering Allégorie de la caverne.}

\startparwith{%
  L’allégorie de\\
  la caverne
}%
Maintenant, repris-je, représente-toi notre nature, selon qu’elle est ou qu’elle n’est pas éclairée par l’éducation, d’après le tableau que voici. Figure-toi des hommes dans une demeure souterraine en forme de caverne, dont l’entrée, ouverte à la lumière, s’étend sur toute la longueur de la façade ; ils sont là depuis leur enfance, les jambes et le cou pris dans des chaînes, en sorte qu’ils ne peuvent bouger de place, ni voir ailleurs que devant eux ; car les liens les empêchent de tourner la tête ; la lumière d’un feu allumé au loin sur une hauteur brille derrière eux ; entre le feu et les prisonniers il y a une route élevée ; le long de cette route figure-toi un petit mur, pareil aux cloisons que les montreurs de marionnettes dressent entre eux et le public et au-dessus desquelles ils font voir leurs prestiges.

\end{document}
```

[image: using wrapfig2]

Please see the manuals of the packages for more information about the arguments and additional features like putting the text in a colored box.

Just as note: Usage of [package `lettrine`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lettrine) would also be possible, but is somehow tricky, to avoid increasing of font size of the *faked* letter:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,french]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\newcommand{\startparwith}[2][3]{%
  \lettrine[lines=#1,depth=1,nindent=0pt]{%
    \parbox[b]{.333\textwidth}{\centering\normalsize\bfseries\itshape #2}%
  }{}%
}  

\begin{document}

\section*{\centering Allégorie de la caverne.}

\startparwith{%
  L’allégorie de\\
  la caverne
}%
Maintenant, repris-je, représente-toi notre nature, selon qu’elle est ou qu’elle n’est pas éclairée par l’éducation, d’après le tableau que voici. Figure-toi des hommes dans une demeure souterraine en forme de caverne, dont l’entrée, ouverte à la lumière, s’étend sur toute la longueur de la façade ; ils sont là depuis leur enfance, les jambes et le cou pris dans des chaînes, en sorte qu’ils ne peuvent bouger de place, ni voir ailleurs que devant eux ; car les liens les empêchent de tourner la tête ; la lumière d’un feu allumé au loin sur une hauteur brille derrière eux ; entre le feu et les prisonniers il y a une route élevée ; le long de cette route figure-toi un petit mur, pareil aux cloisons que les montreurs de marionnettes dressent entre eux et le public et au-dessus desquelles ils font voir leurs prestiges.

\end{document}
```

[image: using lettrine]